# Drupal 8 Query Questions

Tags: 8, database

Is there a reason to be using `\Drupal::database()` vs `\Drupal\core\Database\Database::getConnection()`?

How do I know when I can chain my query methods and when I can not? For example

```
$db = \Drupal\core\Database\Database::getConnection();

$query = $db->select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', ['nid'])
  ->condition('type', 'blog');

$results = $query->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

vs

```
$db = \Drupal\core\Database\Database::getConnection();

$query = $db->select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', ['nid']);
$query->fields('nb', ['body_value']);
$query->join('node__body', 'nb', 'n.nid = nb.entity_id');
$query->condition('n.type', 'blog');

$results = $query->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: The second question really doesn't pertain to Drupal specifically, and is more of a generic question. I think that answer is going to be opinionated and preferential based on how you develop code. Either use an IDE to help you or look up the methods in the API if you prefer to use an editor without intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a reason to be using \Drupal::database() vs \Drupal\core\Database\Database::getConnection()?

Yes. The former returns a correctly instantiated service object, with all required dependencies automatically injected. You would need to load up all the relevant services yourself and inject them manually if using the latter method.

> How do I know when I can chain my query methods and when I can not?

There are 2 common approaches:

1. Read the docs for the methods you're using.
2. Use an IDE with good code completion.

Comment: Was just about to type this up in the same format. :-)

Comment: Yeah I was expecting at least a couple of almost-identical answers to already be here by the time I was done writing @mradcliffe!

Comment: So why is the latter an option? Also the docs just specify that join() and innerJoin() join against another table... Not as to why I wouldn't be able to chain and why I would. Still lost on that. It's not that I didn't look at the docs. I just feel like maybe I'm looking at the wrong doc?? I'm looking in the `Selectinterface.php` file.

Comment: The code for the service needs to live somewhere - why not there? The method needs to be public, so you could consider its availability to be a side-effect. Or it may have been intentional for some obscure other reason that only the person(s) who wrote it would know. The join methods return the alias that was assigned to the join, some callers need that. The only other option for that would be to accept an extra parameter by reference and populate it, but that's quite an outdated approach these days.

Comment: So I just don't know how all of this data is connected in order to follow what is going on. So that's the next goal... woohoo. Thanks for the info.